# Website for dialect differences

Tags: discussion

Is there a website where one might find a list or dictionary or difference dialect differences, -not just kansai- or "slang" of certain regions or prefectures?

Comment: The term you're looking for is 方言辞典

Comment: See also the Japanese Wikipedia page [日本語の方言の比較表](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E8%A1%A8)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a couple of links for your reference:

http://www.kansaiben.com/

This appears to hold a list of all dialects in Nihongo:

http://www.nihongoresources.com/language/dialects/kansaiben.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As ssb already commented on your question on main, you're looking for 方言辞典 "dialect dictionaries".

The two online sources I know are

- [Weblio 方言](http://www.weblio.jp/cat/dialect)
  A fairly comprehensive dictionary, sourced from dictionaries for individual dialects across the web.
- http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/dialect/
  A free online version of the paper dictionary 全国方言辞典 published by 三省堂 ([Sanseidō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanseido)).